# akka-streams stateful substream flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

There is a stateful flow:

```
val stream = Flow[Event].statefulMapConcat {
  () =>

    val state = ...

    {
      element =>
        // change the state
        element :: Nil
    }
}
```

and it is a part of the flow

```
Flow[Event]
  .groupBy(1000000, event => event.key2, allowClosedSubstreamRecreation = true)
  .via(stream)
  .mergeSubstreams
```

Is there any way to have a `state` in `stream` per substream (in this example per key after the groupBy)?
I think it should be materialised per sub-stream, but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do get a state per substream in that setup:

```
  val stream = Flow[Int].statefulMapConcat {
    () => {

      var state: List[Int] = Nil

      element => {
        state = element :: state
        List(state)
      }
    }
  }

  val groupByFlow =
  Flow[Int]
    .groupBy(1000000, identity, allowClosedSubstreamRecreation = true)
    .via(stream)
    .mergeSubstreams

  Source(List(1,1,2,3,3,3))
    .via(groupByFlow)
    .runForeach(i => println(i))
```

will print

```
List(1)
List(1, 1)
List(3)
List(2)
List(3, 3)
List(3, 3, 3)
```